# Jython 2.7b4 will not webstart: ImportError: No module named site

Tags: jython, java-web-start

I injected my application into `jython-standalone-2.7-b4.jar`.  Here is what I see in the webstart console of the client machine when I webstart my app:

```
Java Web Start 11.31.2.13
Using JRE version 1.8.0_31-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = C:\Users\me
...
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### null
```

When I click on 'Details', I find the following exception stack trace:

```
ImportError: No module named site

    at org.python.core.ImportError(Py.java:328)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:842)
    at org.python.core.imp.load(imp.java:695)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:118)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.<init>(InteractiveInterpreter.java:39)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.<init>(InteractiveInterpreter.java:28)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.<init>(InteractiveConsole.java:67)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.<init>(InteractiveConsole.java:53)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.<init>(InteractiveConsole.java:33)
    ...
```

Jython2.7b1 worked for me.  I tried Jython2.7b3, but that fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to class loader differences in the Web Start environment, Jython can't find the files in the `Lib` directory inside the standalone jar file. To fix this, you need to rearrange the contents of the standalone jar a bit. The following script will convert a standalone jar into something workable in a Web Start environment:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Converts a Jython standalone jar into something usable with Java Web Start
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "Please give the path to the standalone jar as the first argument."
  exit 1
fi

CURRDIR=$(pwd)
JAR_PATH="$CURRDIR/$1"
CONVERTED_JAR_PATH="$CURRDIR/jython-webstart.jar"
TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$TEMPDIR"
jar xf "$JAR_PATH"
rm -rf Lib/test  # including Jython's own unit tests is pointless
java -jar "$JAR_PATH" -m compileall Lib
find Lib -name "*.py" -delete
mv Lib/* .
rmdir Lib
jar cf "$CONVERTED_JAR_PATH" *
rm -rf "$TEMPDIR"
```

Next you'll probably run into [Jython bug 2283](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2283). To work around it, set the `python.home` system property to point to any existing directory.

Comment: This solves my webstart problem.  I encounter an entirely different problem that can be circumvented by moving back to Jython2.7b3.